# Input file filtered permit to load multipage pdf

Tags: javascript, file, input, filter, upload

In my website, I have an input file prompt that is filtered for images.

The prompt work well and only images file are directly selectable.

The issue is that if I find a multipage pdf in my directory and I start to navigate pages inside the prompt the pdf file is selected and can be updated.

There is a way to prevent this weird behaviour?

[Video YouTube of the issue](https://youtu.be/B0mB8endcR8)

Comment: Didn't understand can you show some demo please?

Comment: I try to make a video of the issue and will post it. I can't explain better sorry.

Comment: I added a video to my issue. Thanks